# Real time human detection in Python openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Now I am writing real-time human detection program in Python2.7 with openCV.
A code I wrote was seriously slow which is referring to [[sample code]](https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/peopledetect.py)

The code I wrote is below.

```
from cv import *

def inside(r, q):
    (rx, ry), (rw, rh) = r
    (qx, qy), (qw, qh) = q
    return rx > qx and ry > qy and rx + rw < qx + qw and ry + rh < qy + qh

NamedWindow("people detection demo", 1)
storage = CreateMemStorage(0) 
capture = CaptureFromCAM(0)
SetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 600)
SetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 450)
while True:
    img = QueryFrame(capture)
    found = list(HOGDetectMultiScale(img, storage, win_stride=(8,8),
                                     padding=(32,32), scale=1.05, group_threshold=2))
    found_filtered = []
    for r in found:
        insidef = False
        for q in found:
            if inside(r, q):
                insidef = True
                break
        if not insidef:
            found_filtered.append(r)
    for r in found_filtered:
        (rx, ry), (rw, rh) = r
        tl = (rx + int(rw*0.1), ry + int(rh*0.07))
        br = (rx + int(rw*0.9), ry + int(rh*0.87))
        Rectangle(img, tl, br, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    ShowImage("people detection demo", img)
    if WaitKey(10) == ord('q'):
        break
```

Only one image could be process nicely, but I would like to implement real-time one.
Does anyone know how to speed up real-time human detection program?

Comment: GPPK probably meant: use the cv2 api (which indeed wraps the c++ one and not the old c-api) . also: the cv module won't be available in the next releases, so really time for a change !

Comment: btw, the github repo above is an outdated fork, use https://github.com/itseez/opencv instead

Comment: @ami_GS: you try to reduce the region of interest to regions where any humans can be. For example for a static camera you could try background subtraction and use the detector only around regions where something moved. At the end it depends on your concrete task whether you can simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak scale param. It means how much detector scales tracking window, namely it starts from some fixes size and if does not find, multiplies the size by the scale factor etc. It does not have to be 1.05, you can set 1.1 or 1.2 or even higher to balance the time consumption and detect rate (don't set to too high because detect rate lowers quickly).

If you don't have to use python, consider using c++ API. It has GPU support which can speed up several times.